# How to only allow of users to select one question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when my users sign up they have to pick three security questions and answer. Within the question I have six questions those are defined as helper methods for example here is a picture

[image: security questions example]

Is there any way I can take away a prompt question after being selected the first time? For example for the first question they select "What is your father middle name". Now for the second question they cant select that prompt question any more because they already answered it the first time.

Here's my code below

```
<%= f.fields_for :role do |r| %>
  <%= r.fields_for :user do |u| %>
    <% i = 0 %>
    <%= u.fields_for :security_questions do |ff| %>
      <div class="group">
        <%= ff.select :key, options_for_select(sec_questions, selected: i), {}, { :class => 'half' } %>
        <%= ff.text_field :value, placeholder: "Answer #{i+1}", class: "half", "data-validate": '["empty"]' %>
        <div class="push"></div>
      </div><!--group-->
      <% i = i+1 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Apart from this specific implementation, please be aware that this kind of "security questions" is generally considered a security anti-pattern since most of this information is often public or semi-public which significantly reduces their value. Also, due toi the generally small amount of possible (or common) answers, a brute-force attack is easy. Thus, you should generally use other means to protect your users, e.g. two-factor authentication with e.g. [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) or [U2F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor).

Comment: What's the flow of your implementation, every time you select an option do you send the data to your server? or the data is sent after all the options are selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the already used option as disabled.

the `[options_for_select][1]` have the possibility to set some `disabled_options`

```
options_for_select(["Free", "Basic", "Advanced", "Super Platinum"], disabled: "Super Platinum")

# => <option value="Free">Free</option>
# => <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
# => <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
# => <option value="Super Platinum" disabled="disabled">Super Platinum</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some jquery to do this

for example

```
$(document).ready ->
  questionOpts = $(".questions select:first option")

  $(".questions select").change ->
    trigger = this

    $(".questions select").each ->
      select = this

      if select != trigger
        selectedValues = $(".questions select").map -> 
          if this != select
            this.value if this.value != ""

        opts = questionOpts.clone().map -> 
          if jQuery.inArray(this.value, selectedValues) == -1
            if this.value == select.value
              $(this).prop("selected", true)
            this

        $(select).empty()
        $(select).append(opts)


  $(".questions select").trigger("change")
```

```
<div class="questions">
  <select name="x">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <select name="y">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
  <select name="z">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```